# Python BeautifulSoup scrape site with filter

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

im trying to scrape https://www.forexfactory.com/calendar?day=today .
My code is

```
table = soup.find_all("tr",{"class":"calendar_row"})
    
forcal = []
for item in table:
    dict = {}
    
    dict["Currency"] = item.find_all("td", {"class":"calendar__currency"})[0].text.strip() #Currency
    dict["Event"] = item.find_all("td",{"class":"calendar__event"})[0].text.strip() #Event Name
    dict["Time_Eastern"] = item.find_all("td", {"class":"calendar__time"})[0].text #Time Eastern
    impact = item.find_all("td", {"class":"impact"})
    
    for icon in range(0,len(impact)):
        dict["Impact"] = impact[icon].find_all("span")[0]['title'].split(' ', 1)[0]

    dict["Actual"] = item.find_all("td", {"class":"calendar__actual"})[0].text #Actual Value
    dict["Forecast"] = item.find_all("td", {"class":"calendar__forecast"})[0].text #forecasted Value
    dict["Previous"] = item.find_all("td", {"class":"calendar__previous"})[0].text # Previous
    forcal.append(dict)
```

I am able to scrape all the data. But how do i filter for USD currency only? Currently it's scraping all currency.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an if statement before you assign the values to the dictionary:

```py
Currency = item.find_all("td", {"class":"calendar__currency"})[0].text.strip() #Currency
if Currency == "USD":
    dict["Currency"] = Currency
    dict["Event"] = item.find_all("td",{"class":"calendar__event"})[0].text.strip()
    ...
```